# iOS UIScrollView copies images to background

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Good day,

my problem is as follows:
I have a scrollview and I add multiple windows to them. Between them is a small empty space. When I scroll the images move but a 'copy' of them stays on the background.
If I wouldn't have the empty spaces between the images you wouldn't see it, but filling it with a color isn't the solution because the mainview has a background image that should be visible through the gaps.

Anyone any idea?

code:

```
 lookbookScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 490.0f, 768.0f, 375.0f)];
[lookbookScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[lookbookScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(([books count] * 275) + 20, 375)];
[self.view addSubview:lookbookScroll];

for (int i = 0; i < [books count]; i++) 
{
    UIButton *tmpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [tmpButton setFrame:CGRectMake((i * 275) + 20, 0, 265, 375)];
    [tmpButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [tmpButton setBackgroundImage:[[books objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tmpButton setTag:[[books objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Id"]];
    [tmpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(readBook:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [lookbookScroll addSubview:tmpButton];
}
```

Comment: When is this code being called ? Is there any chance that it gets called twice and produces two scrollviews one on top of the other ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your specific problem, but if `[books count]` is anything large you're going to get poor scrolling performance. Consider using [content tiling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) for much better performance.

Comment: Books count gives a value lower then 5. If it becomes higher we will use dynamic loading/unloading but currently that isn't necessary but thanks for the tip. Currently it is done in the view did load, and i just looks at the logs and it looks indeed like it is called twice, i'm going to check it right away. Thanks, update comes soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adig was right, it was placed in the view did load and it got called twice. Placed it in the init now and that solved the problem. Much thanks for the quick replies.